# In mobile mp4 video is not working?

Tags: html, video, html5-video

In mobile mp4 video not working, it display only img of video.

I don't know how this problem solve.Link is here 
http://innovatoryinfotech.com/theme/Restora/index-video.html

This is my html.

```
 <video id="video" class="slider-video" width="100%" preload="auto" loop autoplay style="visibility: visible; width: 100%;">
          <source src="video/Sushi-361.mp4">
          <source src="video/Sushi-361.webm" type="video/webm">
          <source src="video/Sushi-361.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        </video>
```

Please solve this problem.

i add this script

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
},false);
```

then it work when click in the img then video is start.

But how to start automatic video on mobile.

Comment: specify the type `type="video/mp4"`

Comment: i try that but not work

Comment: it works on my device, specify the OS of the device because iOS and android have different methodology for handling web videos

Comment: it not work in android mobile in Iphone i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "not working", it's just `preload` and `autoplay` disabled. In iOS Safari, you can't make video play until user explicitly start it.

Here is the official [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1) description:

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, `preload` and `autoplay` are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.

UPDATE: according to https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay, `autoplay` was disabled in some versions of Chrome on Android too. However, "muted autoplay" is supported by Chrome for Android as of version 53, and is supported by Safari on iOS 10 and later.

Thus, you can try to fix this issue by adding `muted` attribute (`<video autoplay muted>`). However, due to browser history, it won't work on all devices.